# nodejs webpack server not starting

Tags: node.js, webpack

I am new to NodeJs and trying to setup react app. Getting following error on the console while starting the server.

Not able to start the server, have tried several options.

```
c:\Users\vaibhav\Desktop\node>npm start

> test@1.0.0 start c:\Users\vaibhav\Desktop\node
> webpack-dev-server --hot

x ?wds?: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module has an unknown property 'loaders'. These properties are valid:
   object { exprContextCritical?, exprContextRecursive?, exprContextRegExp?, exprContextRequest?, noParse?, rules?, defaultRules?, unknownContextCritical?, unknownContextRecursive?, unknownContextRegExp?, unknownContextRequest?, unsafeCache?, wrappedContextCritical?, wrappedContextRecursive?, wrappedContextRegExp?, strictExportPresence?, strictThisContextOnImports? }
   -> Options affecting the normal modules (`NormalModuleFactory`).
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! test@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --hot`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the test@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log
ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\vaibhav\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-09-06T17_00_03
_303Z-debug.log
```

The log file shows the following error:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v8.11.4
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle test@1.0.0~prestart: test@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle test@1.0.0~start: test@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle test@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle test@1.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;c:\Users\vaibhav\Desktop\node\node_modules\.bin;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows\system32\wbem;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\app\vaibhav\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Attachmate\E!E2K\;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Attachmate\Reflection\;C:\Users\vaibhav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36;C:\Users\vaibhav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts;C:\Strawberry\c\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\site\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\bin;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\1E\NomadBranch\;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Users\vaibhav\Documents\softwares\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG;C:\Program Files (x86)\Enterprise Vault\EVClient\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_152\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\WebEx\Productivity Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\CheckPoint\Endpoint Security\Endpoint Common\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\vaibhav\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\vaibhav\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle test@1.0.0~start: CWD: c:\Users\vaibhav\Desktop\node
10 silly lifecycle test@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'webpack-dev-server --hot' ]
11 silly lifecycle test@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle test@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: test@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --hot`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:285:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid test@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd c:\Users\vaibhav\Desktop\node
16 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "start"
18 verbose node v8.11.4
19 verbose npm  v5.6.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error test@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --hot`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the test@1.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

My package.json looks like the following:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "webpack": "^4.17.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

Please let me know in case you require more details. I will provide that in comments.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your question: 
`wds?: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module has an unknown property 'loaders'. These properties are valid:    object { exprContextCritical?, exprContextRecursive?, exprContextRegExp?, exprContextRequest?, noParse?, rules?, defaultRules?, unknownContextCritical?, unknownContextRecursive?, unknownContextRegExp?, unknownContextRequest?, unsafeCache?, wrappedContextCritical?, wrappedContextRecursive?, wrappedContextRegExp?, strictExportPresence?, strictThisContextOnImports? }`

In your config, instead of `module.loaders`, it has to be `module.rules`.